# return list of validation errors on field in pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Is it possible to return a list of validation errors for a specific field, without having separate validators for the same field? It would be nice to get all errors back in 1 shot for the field, instead of having to get separate responses back for each failed validation.

```
@validator('password')
def check_password(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()

    failed = []

    min_length = 8
    if len(password) < min_length:
        failed.append('Password must be at least 8 characters long.')
        return value

    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        failed.append('Password missing lower case')
        return value

   if len(failed) > 0:
      raise ValueError(failed)
```

Output:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "password"
            ],
            "msg": "['Password must be at least 8 characters long.', 'Password missing lower case']",
            "type": "assertion_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, `"msg"` comes as a string list. Can we get that as a list?

Comment: `assert len(password) >= min_length, "Password must be at least 8 characters long."`?

Comment: I was testing returning a list of strings there, but that is what I want. I would have a list setup and for each failed validation append the failure message, and I want to return 1 list of all failures on the password field @CristiFati

Comment: unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: so you want a list `["a", "b", "c"]` instead of a string `"[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]"` right?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom yes for failed validations in pydantic

Comment: @OrenIshShalom to my knowledge, there isn't a supported method to return multiple validations back on the same field, so I'm trying to check multiple conditions on the same field, and return back a list of any failed validations

Answer (score 2):

Here is my "caveman approach" for this problem - unwrap the string list with regex:

```
import re
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator

class UserModel(BaseModel):

    username: str
    password: str

    @validator("password")
    def passwords_match(cls, v):
        errors = []
        if "7" in v:
            errors.append("Illegal password")
        if len(v) < 4:
            errors.append("too short")
        if errors:
            raise ValueError(errors)

        return v

try:
    UserModel(
        username='scolvin',
        password='gg7'
    )
except ValidationError as e:
    for error in e.errors():
        error_msg = error["msg"]
        L = [m[0][1:-1] for m in re.finditer("'[^']*'", error_msg)]
        error["msg"] = L
    print(e.json())
```

It contains a complete reproducible minimal example and solution. It is indeed not that elegant, but might just be what solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

If you check out the [class delcaration ValidationError](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/e9327b85fc5f3e14ae3efdd142c68478f6899dc9/pydantic/error_wrappers.py#L50) In the repository for pydantic, you  see [how the msg prop is generated](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/e9327b85fc5f3e14ae3efdd142c68478f6899dc9/pydantic/error_wrappers.py#L120) using the method `error_dict`

In `error_dict` `msg` is generated using the following code :

```py
 type_ = get_exc_type(exc.__class__)
    msg_template = config.error_msg_templates.get(type_) or getattr(exc, 'msg_template', None)
    ctx = exc.__dict__
    if msg_template:
        msg = msg_template.format(**ctx)
    else:
        msg = str(exc)
```

Which will always return a string, no matter what you pass to your `ValueError` constructor.

Furthermore, splitting your function into multiple validators doesn't seem to work either, as pydantic will only report the first failing validator

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    password: str

    @validator("password")
    def is_lower_case(cls, value):
        if not value.islower():
            raise ValueError("Must be lower")
        return value
        
    @validator("password")
    def is_long_enough(cls, value):
        if len(value) < 3:
            raise ValueError("Too short")
        return value
```

Output:

```sh
>>> from test_model import TestModel
>>> TestModel(password="Te")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TestModel
password
  Must be lower (type=value_error)
```

Comment: Please see my own answer, to see if you agree in this case, or if you have any other feedback! Thanks for taking time to share your thoughts @Araelath

Comment: You didn't specify that you were working with FastAPI. Indeed in that case, a custom exceptions handler seems to be the correct approach!

Answer (score 0):

Decided to add a middleware to FastAPI as a low touch approach to solving this for my use case. I do not want to modify / manage custom installations of pydantic, so adding a middleware to my API seems like a better alternative, for now?

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    errors = []

    for each in exc.errors():
        error = {"message" if key == "msg" else key: ast.literal_eval(value) if value[0] == '[' and value[-1] == ']' else value for key, value in each.items()}
        errors.append(error)

    return JSONResponse({"detail": errors}, status_code = 422)
```

Above logic is renaming the `"msg"` key to `"message"`, and converting list representations in a string to a list.

Comment: Isn't super clean, because some values in "msg" will be string without potential list representation, so I'm checking first if it contains brackets [].

Answer (score -1):

You can use ast.literal_eval on msg field value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).